# Не работает конфигурация NGINX "Раздача статического содержимого" из руководства для начинающих

Tags: nginx

Всё делал по [инструкции в руководстве для начинающих](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html). Единственное что добавил это код ниже в файл `nginx.conf`, в начало блока `http`. В результате 404 ошибка. По полному пути `/data/www/` и `/data/images/1.jpg` всё работает. Перезагружал и конфигурацию, и NGINX, и всю систему.

```
server {
    location / {
        root /data/www;
    }
    location /images/ {
        root /data;
    }
}
```

Файл [/etc/nginx/nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d5aff65019c9915e421f8dca707a7746)

Comment: Никаких других `server` у вас нету? Вроде бы nginx из коробки всегда имеет какой-нибудь `server` по умолчанию, и возможно ваша конфигурация конфликтует с конфигурацией по умолчанию

Comment: устанавливали-то откуда? из официального репозитория взяли или по ссылке из приведённого вами руководства, т.е., «левые» сборки от самих nginx-овцев?

Comment: Кстати, полезно будет выполнить `sudo nginx -t` и почитать результат, там могут написать о каких-нибудь проблемах с конфигом вроде тех же конфликтов

Comment: @andreymal Других блоков `server` нет. Файл: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d5aff65019c9915e421f8dca707a7746

Comment: `include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;` вот тут что лежит?

Comment: @Hipster как минимум вон прописаны `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` и `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`, а там уже что угодно может лежать и мешаться

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Из официального репозитория Debian командой `$ sudo apt install nginx`.

Comment: $ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: @Hipster, тогда вам надо убрать всё что вы добавляли и править секцию server в `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Всё равно ничего не работает.

Comment: «ничего» — это слишком много. вы укажите в вопросе, что именно и куда добавили, какие файлы/каталоги создали, какие запросы отправляете, какие ответы получаете.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Добавил 3 строчки с `location /images/`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cef12862e0d177d94ac0e0647326387e в результате по `/images/1.jpg` всё равно 404 ошибка. По полному пути `/data/images/1.jpg` картинка открывается.

Comment: reload или restart после изменения конфигурации делали? какую именно команду вы выполняете для получения файла? внеся такую же секцию location как у вас, создав файл `/data/images/1.jpg` и выполнив `$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload` я получаю правильные заголовки командой `$ wget -S --spider http://127.0.0.1/images/1.jpg`. вы же не первый день на сайте. впишите в текст вопроса то, что делаете, пожалуйста.

Comment: покажи `ls -la /data`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Давайте по порядку. 1. Я внёс три строчки в файл `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67deabca354506742bd81e0b79532494 (предварительно создав `/var/www/html/data/images/1.jpg`) 2. `sudo nginx -s reload`. 3. Зайдя на `/data/images/1.jpg` через браузер или `wget -S --spider http://127.0.0.1/data/images/1.jpg` я получаю 200. Если без `/data` то 404. ПО: Debian GNU/Linux 9.2 (stretch), nginx=1.10.3-1+deb9u1

Comment: директивой root указывается абсолютный путь внутри файловой системы. раз файл у вас не в `/data/images`, а в `/var/www/html/data/images`, то так и укажите в location-е: `root /var/www/html/data;`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin всё понял. всем спасибо за терпение.